# How to drawing bitmap in runnable?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, draw, runnable

I want to draw bitmap in runnable but dont work.
The code gives an exit error from the application.
I commented the non-working part in the code.

```
 private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {


                // This code block dont run. Application exit error.
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                rect = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                canvas.drawArc(rect, 0F, 360F, true, paint);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView.invalidate();

                customHandler.postDelayed(this, showTime);
   

                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            
         }
    };
```

Comment: What do you mean “dont run”? Did you actually call on this code to run? Did you submit an instance of this `Runnable` to an executor service?

Comment: This code run normally in protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}. But this code dont run in private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() { }. I try but program give Application exit error. I want to draw bitmap in Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

## Submit your `Runnable` to an `ExecutorService`

Your question is not clear. But taking your question as written, I’ll guess you neglected to call upon the code shown. A `Runnable` does not magically execute itself. You must submit an instance of your `Runnable` to an executor service.

Given the variable name `updateTimeThread`, I am guessing you want this code to run repeatedly on a background thread. So we need a *scheduled* executor service to run repeatedly.

That name shows some confusion on your part. A `Runnable` is *not* a thread. A `Runnable` is a task to be executed by an `ExecutorService` on one of its managed threads.

Let’s define a simpler runnable to get some rudimentary code up and running.

```java
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println( "Running the run method at " + Instant.now() ) ;
    }
}
```

Establish your executor service.

```java
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
```

Submit an instance of your `Runnable` to be run every so often.

```java
long delay = 0 ; 
long period = 1 ;
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( task , delay , period , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Be sure to eventually shut down your executor service. Otherwise its backing thread pool may continue to run indefinitely, like a zombie ‍♂️.

And as with nearly all GUI toolkits, in Android never access the UI widgets from a background thread. Do calculations on the background thread. But when it comes time to update the UI use whatever mechanism is provided to ask the UI thread to run some code to update the UI widgets. (I don’t know Android’s mechanism.)